# Oracle strange behavior when grouping by a TIMESTAMP field when the values are on the daylight saving border

Tags: oracle, timezone, timestamp, dst, timestamp-with-timezone

I have a strange behavior of Oracle DB with TIMESTAMP and daylight saving.

The following query produces different results when grouping by different columns and it is not clear why.

When grouping by **my_date_ny_ts** it returns two different rows and when by **my_date_ny_ts_tz** - the result is only one row (the right one for me).

Please note the values are for the 11/04/2018 00:00:00 -05:00 and 11/04/2018 00:00:00 -06:00 that are converted to the New_York timezone to 11-04-2018 01:00 and 02:00 EDT which are actually 01:00 EDT and 01:00 EST.

I understand why those values are different, but they should be equal after converting them to the TIMESTAMP without time zone data type (the **my_date_ny_ts** column), since this type doesn't contain any information about timezone and daylight saving status (see the **tdz_ny_ts** values). Only after I convert the values back to the TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE type (the **my_date_ny_ts_tz**) they become equal.
I don't need a workaround (already have it), just wondering if this behavior is an Oracle bug or by misunderstanding:

```
select count(*), my_date_ny_ts_tz from (

SELECT
 mydate, -- timestamp with timezone
 to_char( mydate, 'TZD') as tdz, -- daylight savings flag - VALUES are NULL because timezone is an offset
 mydate AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York' AS mydate_ny, -- timestamp with timezone in EST timezone
 to_char( mydate AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York', 'TZD') as tdz_ny, --timestamp with timezone in EST timezone -  daylight savings flag - RETURNS EDT FOR ONE EST FOR SECOND - RIGHT
cast(mydate AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York' as timestamp)  as my_date_ny_ts,--cast to timestamp without timezone - GROUP BY RETURNS TWO ROWS - BUG?
to_char( cast(mydate AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York' as timestamp) , 'TZD') as tdz_ny_ts,--cast to timestamp without timezone -  daylight savings flag - both values are null so why the group by on the prev field doesn't work?
 cast(mydate AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York' as timestamp) AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York' as my_date_ny_ts_tz,--cast back to timestamp with timezone in EST timezone - NOW GROUP BY RETURNS ONE ROW
 to_char( cast(mydate AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York' as timestamp) AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York', 'TZD') as tdz_ny_ts_tz--daylight savings flag of the prev field - both are EST - RIGHT
 FROM
     (
         SELECT
         to_timestamp_tz('11/04/2018 00:00:00 -05:00','mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss TZH:TZM') AS mydate
     FROM
         dual
     UNION
     SELECT
         to_timestamp_tz('11/04/2018 00:00:00 -06:00','mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss TZH:TZM') AS mydate
     FROM
         dual
 )
 ) group by my_date_ny_ts_tz
```

My version is the following, but it happens in 12c as well:

```
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
"CORE   11.2.0.4.0  Production"
TNS for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be a bug in Oracle. You can shorten the query to this:

```
SELECT 
    TO_CHAR(CAST(TIMESTAMP '2018-11-04 00:00:00 -05:00' AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York' AS TIMESTAMP), 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') AS my_date_ny_ts,
    DUMP(CAST(TIMESTAMP '2018-11-04 00:00:00 -05:00' AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York' AS TIMESTAMP)) AS my_date_ny_ts_dump
FROM DUAL 
UNION ALL
SELECT
    TO_CHAR(CAST(TIMESTAMP '2018-11-04 00:00:00 -06:00' AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York' AS TIMESTAMP), 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'),
    DUMP(CAST(TIMESTAMP '2018-11-04 00:00:00 -06:00' AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York' AS TIMESTAMP))
FROM DUAL;


+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|MY_DATE_NY_TS      |MY_DATE_NY_TS_DUMP                                                |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|2018-11-04 01:00:00|Typ=187 Len=20: 226,7,11,4,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,252,0,3,0,100,0,11,3   |
|2018-11-04 01:00:00|Typ=187 Len=20: 226,7,11,4,1,0,0,48,0,0,0,0,251,0,3,44,100,0,48,44|
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

As you see the timestamp values are the same, however the `DUMP()` values are different, i.e. you get two rows if you make `GROUP BY`.

You can run it slightly different. Actually I would expect the same result as above (no matter wether you consider that as correct or not) but it is different:

```
WITH t AS
    (SELECT 
        CAST(TIMESTAMP '2018-11-04 00:00:00 -05:00' AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York' AS TIMESTAMP) AS my_date_ny_ts
    FROM DUAL 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        CAST(TIMESTAMP '2018-11-04 00:00:00 -06:00' AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York' AS TIMESTAMP)
    FROM DUAL)
SELECT TO_CHAR(my_date_ny_ts, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') AS my_date_ny_ts,
    DUMP(my_date_ny_ts) AS my_date_ny_ts_dump
FROM t;

    +--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|MY_DATE_NY_TS      |MY_DATE_NY_TS_DUMP                                                |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|2018-11-04 01:00:00|Typ=180 Len=7: 120,118,11,4,2,1,1                                 |
|2018-11-04 01:00:00|Typ=180 Len=7: 120,118,11,4,2,1,1                                 |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

This looks strange to me. Although I made `CAST(... AS TIMESTAMP)` for both, once I get `Typ=187` and once I get `Typ=180` in DUMP.

Looks like the SQL type `TIMESTAMP` 180 (see [Oracle Built-In Data Types](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41085/sqlqr06002.htm#r10c1-t3)) behaves different than the PL/SQL type `TIMESTAMP` 187 (see PACKAGE `SYS.dbms_types`) - but I don't know why.

For the workaround I would suggest to use function `SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(...)` rather than `CAST(... AS TIMESTAMP)`.